# PHP Fractal transformers - Multiple Transformers for a single model?

Tags: php, api, laravel, transform, lumen

Is it better to have multiple `Transformers` over a single transformer per model?

**e.g.**

I want to *exclude* a fields from the JSON response when *listing* items. Although when retrieving a single item I want all fields. Would a `PostListTransformer` and a `PostTransformer` be appropriate, or should i use the *"includes"* feature of Fractal?

Also I would like the ability to include extra fields AND relations in the `PostListTransformer`.

Examples will be well regarded, Laravel Eloquent is the ORM.

Comment: Fractal Transformers are intended to always generate the same output. I would suggest to use multiple Transformers if you want various output and use these Transformers as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a $fields property that gets populated with the fields you only need through your transformer's constructor method, then create a method that uses those fields (if any exist) to filter out your transform() method output. You can find some code for it in one of the closed issues in the fractal github repo

https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal/issues/226#issuecomment-156802672